# How do I create a portal for this navbar (React)

Tags: reactjs

This is my index.html (Where the portal is supposed to lead to)

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="navbarRoot"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Here is my navbar component

```
const Navbar = () => {

const [isOpen , setIsOpen] = useState(false)

const navButtonHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
}

  return (
    <>  
    <nav className='navbar'>
         <span><img src={logo} alt='home' className='logo' /></span>
         <div className={`menuMask ${isOpen && "open"}`} onClick={navButtonHandler}></div>
         <div className={`menuContainer ${isOpen && "open"}`}>
         <ul className={`navitems ${isOpen && "open"}`}>
            <a href="/" className='home'>
                <li>Home</li>
            </a>

            <a href="/" className='whoWeHelp'>
                <li>Who We Help</li>
            </a>

            <a href="/" className='services'>
                <li>Services</li>
            </a>

            <a href="/" className='about'>
                <li>About</li>
            </a>

            <a href="/" className='caseStudies'>
                <li>Case Studies</li>
            </a>

            <li>
               <PrimaryButton link={'https://hadizouhbi.website'}>Client Login</PrimaryButton>
            </li>

            <li>
                <SecondaryButton link={'https://hadizouhbi.website'}>Contact</SecondaryButton>
            </li>
         </ul>
         </div>

         <div className={`navToggle ${isOpen && "open"}`}  onClick={navButtonHandler}>
            <div className='bar'>
                
            </div>
         </div>
    </nav>
    </>
  )
}
```

Where in the code do I use this

```
{ReactDom.createPortal(<Navbar />, document.getElementById('navbarRoot'))}
```

Am i doing something wrong? because I have no idea where to put that line however I do think the syntax for that is correct just where to put it is the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated ! I am a beginner to react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to render the whole `NavBar` component as a portal then return in the Navbar should be like below.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const domNode = document.getElementById("navbarRoot");

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const navButtonHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const navContent = (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <span>{/* <img src={logo} alt="home" className="logo" /> */}</span>
        <div
          className={`menuMask ${isOpen && "open"}`}
          onClick={navButtonHandler}
        ></div>
        <div className={`menuContainer ${isOpen && "open"}`}>
          <ul className={`navitems ${isOpen && "open"}`}>
            <a href="/" className="home">
              <li>Home</li>
            </a>

            ...
            ...
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div
          className={`navToggle ${isOpen && "open"}`}
          onClick={navButtonHandler}
        >
          <div className="bar"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(navContent, domNode);
};
```

Use `Navbar` in any other place. In spite of where you try to render it in your component tree, it will always appear in the div with `navbarRoot` as the id.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit late-currying-vrncck]

Answer (score 0):

the code `{ReactDom.createPortal(<Navbar />, document.getElementById('navbarRoot'))}` goes inside the **return** statement.

eg:

```
import Navbar from "component"

function MainPage(){
   ...
   ...

   return(
      <> 
         ...
        {ReactDom.createPortal(<Navbar />, document.getElementById('navbarRoot'))}
      </>
   );
}
```